# shell script to check if a glob pattern matches any file

Tags: bash, shell, glob

I wrote a shell script to check if a binary is present:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if [ -e "/path/to/a/binary/file/app.bin" ]; then 
     echo "INFO: application has been built successfully" 
else 
     echo "ERROR: application couldn't be built". 
fi
```

It works fine and gives expected results. However if there are many applications with similar name (say `app1.bin, app2.bin` etc) and I want to test for `"app*.bin"` the if condition fails:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

    if [ -e "/path/to/a/binary/file/app*.bin" ]; then 
         echo "INFO: application has been built successfully" 
    else 
         echo "ERROR: application couldn't be built". 
    fi
```

How can i correct the if condition to search for existence of any binary with `app` as name i.e. `app*.bin`

Comment: glob does not work inside quotes. Even if you did remove it, the condition will fail if multiple files are returned from the glob match

Comment: Hi @Inian, so what do you suggest. How should i change the code such that it solves my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to use `compgen -G`: it will generate a list of matching files or it will exit with an error status if nothing matches. With `compgen` you need quotes to prevent expansion.

```
if compgen -G "/path/to/a/binary/file/app*.bin" > /dev/null; then 
     echo "INFO: application has been built successfully" 
else 
     echo "ERROR: application couldn't be built". 
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrea, this is the simplest solution which meets my requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`glob` matching does not work inside quotes. Even if you did remove it, the condition will fail if multiple files are returned from the `glob` match, because the `-e` will work for single file only.

In `bash` you can do this,

```
# the nullglob will let the unmatched glob to handled properly
shopt -s nullglob
fileList=(/path/to/a/binary/file/app*.bin)

if [ "${#fileList[@]}" -ge 1 ]; then
     echo "INFO: application has been built successfully" 
else
     echo "ERROR: application couldn't be built". 
fi

# This line is optional. This is just to ensure the nullglob option is 
# reset after our computation
shopt -u nullglob
```

Comment: @F.Hauri: I do have the `nullgob` option set right(`shopt -s nullglob
`)?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry: I was too quick... (I don't use `nullglob`). Testing with `-e` seem clean and efficient.  Generally I try to not use `shopt` to prevent strong debugging operations.